# Simple CGI web server in Python on VMS

Tags: python, cgi, vms

I am trying to run an extremely simple CGI server on VMS done in python.

```
import sys    
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler    
server_address=('',8080)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The problem I have is that it serves out static content properly and it tries to execute the CGI-s (it is in the right place, and Ihave used those CGIs with Apache so that part is definitely not the issue) but it hangs somewhere. It is something I don't know about VMS.

Any pointer to the right direction would be appreciated. :)

Update: Simplified, I need to execute a program on VMS and get the results of that program somehow. Any reference to executing subprocesses and getting their results is enough for me.

Comment: May be you should post the logs (set `debug=True` in those servers, if present) and give a link. Without these details it is hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: if I telnet to the port and do GET this is what I get: %DCL-W-NOCOMD, no command on line - reenter with alphabetic first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Python port from http://hg.vmspython.org/vmspython/ ?

If so, I think [this thread](http://forum.vmspython.org/viewtopic.php?t=157&sid=924e3d4e4b210f693946057b790bcc0a), and [this file](http://hg.vmspython.org/vmspython/file/4b41453bb7cd/python/vms/vmspopen2.py) (which appears to implement a form of `popen2`), may hold the keys to your salvation. There appear to be VMS-specific modules (at least `vms.starlet`, `vms.rtl.lib`, `vms.dvidef`, `vms.clidef`) in the port that provide interfaces to such things as VMS's `spawn` function. Documentation seems to be spotty or nonexistent, however.

Comment: Thank you, this is the closest to the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

`CGIHTTPServer.py` uses `os.fork` if available, `subprocess.Popen` if not.

See the source code of the [`run_cgi` method](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/CGIHTTPServer.py?view=markup#l225).

Experiment withe the `subprocess` module to see if/how it works on VMS.

Comment: I would love to experiment with subprocess module, only if it was available on the target platform.

Comment: Anything else you can use? ``os.popen2/3``?

Answer (score -1):

To execute a subprocess and get its output on posix:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> output = Popen(['/bin/ls', '/'], stdout = PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> print output
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
..snip..
root
sbin
>>>
```

This is clearly on Linux, so I'm not sure of any VMS specifics to Python or the subprocess module.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Module subprocess is not available on VMS. Also fork() is not there at all.

Comment: Holy crap- if there is no os.fork(), I'm not sure of your options.  I think fork() is the underlying call for most? (all?) of the process creation functions/modules. subprocess, multiprocess, os.spawn*, etc.  does os.system() exist?

Comment: Subprocesses work quite differently on OpenVMS. At the  moment I do not have access to the compiler on the target platform, so Python is only available sane option.

Comment: can you create subprocesses in the command shell, akin to coproc or & in bash?

Comment: Yes, you cans SPAWN a process from shell.